# Does Skill Focus advance automatically?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, optimization

The feat Skill Focus (PCR 134) says,

> You get a +3 bonus on all checks involving the chosen skill. If you have 10 or more ranks in that skill, this bonus increases to +6.

My question is, if I took Skill Focus (Spellcraft) at third level and had 10 ranks in it by level 10, would the bonus automatically increase, or would I have to take it at level 11 with 10 or more ranks for the feat to have the +6 bonus?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Skill Focus begins conferring its increased bonus at the moment that you have 10 ranks in the chosen skill. You only need to spend the one feat to get the +6 increase and then it's automatic after the level-up that gave you the 10th rank or the skill-point from a Headband of Intelligence or other point increase.

***Sidenote:*** If you got your 10th skill point from a Headband of Intelligence and then unequipped it (or similar loss of skill points), if this would bring you to less than 10 ranks in that skill, you lose the +6 and it becomes +3 again.

Answer (score 3):

The feat's text always applies.  If you increase your skill ranks to 10 in a skill that you have Skill Focus in, then you get the bonus of +6.  If you go below 10, then you drop back down to +3 from the feat.